# Проблемы с запуском сервера django

Tags: python, django

В попытках обучения Django, я столкнулся с проблемой создания сервера.

После создания проекта методом  `django-admin startproject name_web`, попробовал запустить сервер таким образом `python manage.py runserver`. Сразу скажу, что я перешёл в папку с файлом "manage.py"

Когда пишу  `python manage.py runserver` мне возвращает строку `Python` и всё на этом. Если повторить эти же операции через cmd, результат такой же, ничего не меняется.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Как делать Правильно?

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Запустите через терминал(`cmd`) без IDE. Что нибудь изменилось?

Comment: нет, вообще ничего не меняется

Comment: Попробуйте все сначала, создать окружение, установить в него джангу, и создать новый проект. По вашему алгоритму все работает. Повторить подобное поведение не получается, первая мысль на отредактированные  файлы джанги но тут сложно что-то сказать.

Comment: погодите, я не создал окружение